# How can I pull a Google Doc spreadsheet into a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Is it possible for me to access a Google Docs spreadsheet (possibly as a CSV file?) and build that into a PHP array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google provides a [PHP API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html) for spreadsheets.